# Importing contact from excel file

Tags: contacts

How can I import contacts to a group in CiviCRM from an excel file?

Kind regards,

Alexia

Answer (score 3):

You can use Import contact screen to add contact in a group. On preview page of import i.e 3rd page, the screen provides ability to add imported contacts into group. Selecting group from the dropdown would add contact(s) to group.

[image]

HTH

Pradeep